# Efficiently search for a prefix range in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

Let's say I want all records with a **prefix** between two user-supplied alphanumeric values of the same length. Thus, if the user enters `A010` and `A025`, I want to return `A0101`, `A0200` and `A0259`.

What I've tried:

1. Obviously, I cannot use `WHERE myText BETWEEN @from and @to`, because that won't return `A0259`.
2. Technically, `WHERE LEFT(myText, @len) BETWEEN @from AND @to`, would be exactly what I want, but that [kills SARGability](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/).
3. I could use `WHERE myText BETWEEN @from and @to + 'zzzzzzzzzzz'`, but that is an ugly hack and potentially error-prone. (Is `z` really the highest character? Did I use enough "padding" characters?)
4. I could "explode" the range and search for every possible prefix, e.g. `WHERE (myText LIKE 'A01%' OR myText LIKE 'A020%' OR myText LIKE 'A021%' ...)`, but that's a lot of work.

Is there some smart solution that I've missed? I'll probably use option 3 to solve the problem (since I know about the length and the range of allowed characters), but I'm curious about the general case.

Comment: I wonder whether `'A02'` should be returned or not. Or `'A01'`. Or `'A01F'` or `'A010F'`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Undefined, undefined, yes, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the `>=` and `<` operators you can return the required range by "increasing the second argument" by 1. Technically, replacing the last character (`'5'`) with the next character (`'6'`) in the character set.

Below is a query that returns all the rows in your range of `A010` and `A025`. To get this I pass `'A026'` as the second argument. The expression `< 'A026'` includes the value `'A0259456546'`.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    Val NVARCHAR(100)
) ;

INSERT @Test
VALUES ('A0004534543'), 
       ('A01034950834'), 
       ('A020043553'), 
       ('A0259456546'), 
       ('A0264565464') ;

SELECT  *

FROM    @Test

WHERE   Val >= 'A010' 
        AND Val < 'A026' ;
```